# JSON-RPC for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, json-rpc, windows-phone-8.1

I have to use JSON-RPC for my Windows phone 8.1 app. I have been google-ing for hours and haven't found anything related to JSON-RPC AND Windows phone 8.1 (or even 8). I have found multiple JSON examples and also JSON-RPC libraries for windows phone 7, but nothing for windows phone 8.1.

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction? It doesn't have to work for Windows Modern and Windows Phone apps both, however it would be prefered.

Comment: If you're not creating an universal app, your library for Windows Phone 7 will work flawlessly with Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: I am working on a universal app, sorry I didn't specify that. Would the library for Windows Phone 7 work for only the phone part of the application? Because for now that would be good enough. Although I'd rather have something that works for both the apps in my universal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/

I had to make slight changes to the code, because some of the things weren't working, since it was made for windows phone 7 and not Windows Universal 8.1. However now it works great, without too much work.

You can find the windows phone 7 code here:
http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AustinHarris.JsonRpc/AustinHarris.JsonRpc.Client.WP7/

Edit: corrected spelling mistakes